# Geth has connected to 3+ peers but won't download blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, geth-debugging, mainnet

I'm trying to run a geth node on my machine. Yesterday I had troubles with finding peers. Today for some reason I'm connecting to many more peers but none of them seem to be willing to serve me any blocks.

I've started my node with `geth --verbosity=4` and I'm seeing up to 7 peers connected to my machine:

```
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:54.392] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=6 id=b62b3fbf2f3a3ee8 duration=217.364ms   req=false err="network ID mismatch: 137 (!= 1)"
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:54.596] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=7 id=b65976f286d02482 conn=dyndial addr=3.18.230.76:30303     name=Geth/v1.10.25-stable...
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:54.755] Ethereum handshake failed                id=b65976f286d02482 conn=dyndial err="network ID mismatch: 4321 (!= 1)"
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:54.756] Message handling failed in `snap`        peer=b65976f2 err=EOF
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:54.756] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=6 id=b65976f286d02482 duration=159.534ms   req=false err="network ID mismatch: 4321 (!= 1)"
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:56.825] Revalidated node                         b=6  id=3ba3110abb4d59c2 checks=2
DEBUG[10-19|11:54:57.188] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=7 id=b6510af6924687f3 conn=dyndial addr=110.43.128.114:30355  name=Geth/v1.1.16-cb131fa...
```

However, it seems that none of these peers are willing to serve me any blocks. I don't see any log lines indicating that my node has ingested/indexed any blocks. Is there something that I may have misconfigured?

Here are the startup logs:

```
11:47AM /Users/paymahn/code/goldsky/firehose/firehose-ethereum/devel/sync-mainnet develop ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ geth --verbosity=4
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.503] Initializing firehose
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.507] Firehose initialized                     enabled=false sync_instrumentation_enabled=true mining_enabled=false block_progress_enabled=false compaction_disabled=false archive_blocks_to_keep=0 genesis_provenance="Geth Default" firehose_version=2.0 geth_version=1.10.25-fh2 chain_variant=geth
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.507] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.507] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.509] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.512] FS scan times                            list="62.291µs" set=209ns diff=791ns
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.513] Sanitizing Go's GC trigger               percent=25
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.513] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.514] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=614.00MiB dirty=1024.00MiB
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.514] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=2.00GiB handles=5120
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.640] Chain freezer table opened               database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain table=receipts items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.641] Chain freezer table opened               database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain table=diffs    items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.641] Chain freezer table opened               database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain table=headers  items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.642] Chain freezer table opened               database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain table=hashes   items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.642] Chain freezer table opened               database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain table=bodies   items=0 size=0.00B
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.642] Opened ancient database                  database=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain readonly=false
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.651] Current full block not old enough        number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 delay=90000
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652] Chain ID:  1 (mainnet)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652] Consensus: Beacon (proof-of-stake), merged from Ethash (proof-of-work)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652] Pre-Merge hard forks:
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Homestead:                   1150000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - DAO Fork:                    1920000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/dao-fork.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): 2463000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): 2675000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): 2675000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Byzantium:                   4370000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Constantinople:              7280000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Petersburg:                  7280000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Istanbul:                    9069000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Muir Glacier:                9200000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/muir-glacier.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Berlin:                      12244000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - London:                      12965000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Arrow Glacier:               13773000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/arrow-glacier.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Gray Glacier:                15050000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/gray-glacier.md)
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652] Merge configured:
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Hard-fork specification:    https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Network known to be merged: true
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Total terminal difficulty:  58750000000000000000000
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]  - Merge netsplit block:       <nil>
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.652]
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.653] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.653] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethash count=2
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.653] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1 dbversion=8
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.663] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=53y6mo3w
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.663] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=53y6mo3w
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.663] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=53y6mo3w
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.663] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.663] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.664] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.664] Chain post-merge, sync via beacon client
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.664] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
WARN [10-19|11:47:43.664] Engine API enabled                       protocol=eth
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.664] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.25-fh2/darwin-arm64/go1.19.2
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.786] TCP listener up                          addr=[::]:30303
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.786] UDP listener up                          addr=[::]:30303
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.788] New local node record                    seq=1,666,122,124,858 id=3b9b1e3a7141f930 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.788] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://3a58de99d66c5155d7ec74b4aab6f0f1da26f03428b2a154072d8caf10650e26bfe913f05e40db5852eea7e3a3073778755fcef2c4ec4461362d08c34f6c514a@127.0.0.1:30303
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.789] IPCs registered                          namespaces=admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,ethash,miner,net,engine
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.789] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.790] Loaded JWT secret file                   path=/Users/paymahn/Library/Ethereum/geth/jwtsecret crc32=0x7d52ee5
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:43.790] Allowed origin(s) for WS RPC interface [localhost]
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.815] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551
INFO [10-19|11:47:43.815] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551 auth=true prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost
DEBUG[10-19|11:47:45.519] Revalidated node                         b=8 id=3b3f58c6b060fdf9 checks=1
INFO [10-19|11:47:46.676] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
```

EDIT: I'm now seeing up to 12 peers but still not getting any blocks.

```
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:44.848] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=10 id=ec97a62d4a91ca1a duration=1.479s      req=true  err="subprotocol error"
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.348] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=11 id=ecab9c270e6d5ee9 conn=dyndial addr=168.119.91.84:30303   name=erigon/v2022.09.3-st...
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.475] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=12 id=b90b3c19f71022b6 conn=inbound addr=47.244.139.58:48072   name=Geth/v1.10.17-stable...
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.475] Ethereum handshake failed                id=b90b3c19f71022b6 conn=inbound err="network ID mismatch: 32520 (!= 1)"
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.476] Message handling failed in `snap`        peer=b90b3c19 err=EOF
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.479] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=11 id=b90b3c19f71022b6 duration=3.924ms     req=false err="network ID mismatch: 32520 (!= 1)"
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.559] Ethereum handshake failed                id=ecab9c270e6d5ee9 conn=dyndial err=EOF
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:45.559] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=10 id=ecab9c270e6d5ee9 duration=211.448ms   req=true  err="disconnect requested"
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:46.969] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=11 id=dabb4732fa387ce4 conn=inbound addr=34.130.142.141:56006  name=Geth/v1.10.23-stable...
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:46.970] Ethereum handshake failed                id=dabb4732fa387ce4 conn=inbound err="network ID mismatch: 10001 (!= 1)"
DEBUG[10-19|11:57:46.970] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=10 id=dabb4732fa387ce4 duration="679.208µs" req=false err="network ID mismatch: 10001 (!= 1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to run a consensus client in beacon mode. The following command worked for me: `lighthouse beacon --datadir=/data --port 9090 --http --http-port 5052 --execution-jwt-id=/ --checkpoint-sync-url=https://mainnet.checkpoint.sigp.io --execution-endpoint=http://host.docker.internal:9551/ --execution-jwt=/sf/jwt.txt` where `/sf/jwt.txt` is the same jwt being used by geth.